# How to prevent background image from covering header and footer

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, header-footer, fancyhdr

I want to introduce a external picture file as the background image by the way of `tikz overlay` option.

The typeset of the following MWE has two problems:

1> header/footer of the first page is covered by the background image.

2> text before the `tikzpicture` enviroment disappeared.

Why? And how to deal with these?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,geometry,fancyhdr,graphicx}
\geometry{showframe}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}\lhead{lhead}
Why is text before the background picture disappeared?
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[inner sep=0] at (current page.center)
{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{A4paper-green.jpg}};
\end{tikzpicture}
Text post the background picture
\clearpage
second page
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You don't need tikz for this. With a current LaTeX you can simply use the shipout hook:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry,fancyhdr,graphicx}
\geometry{showframe}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}\lhead{lhead}
Why is text before the background picture disappeared?
\AddToHookNext{shipout/background}
{\put(0,-\paperheight)
  {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-duck}}}   

Text post the background picture
\clearpage
second page
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your solution. It seems that my latex does not support \AddToHookNext. And where can I find detail explanation about `\AddToHookNext`?

Comment: The new hooks are e.g. described here: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/lthooks-doc.pdf. But you can do something similar on an older system with `eso-pic`.

Comment: Thank you very much for this info. Yes, eso-pic is a good tool For waterprint effect. However for those on current page, tikz seems much easily to control iit position, that's why I intend to use tikz.

Comment: You can still use tikz[overlay, remember picture] with \AddToHookNext (or \AddThispageHook from everypage).  The \put is basically ignored, but it takes two runs instead of one.