# How can I add logo in the background?

Tags: graphics, backgrounds, logos

I run a math club in my school. I want to put our club's logo at the top right corner of the document without hurting the texts in the document, i.e, I want the logo to be in the background. Can I do it?

Comment: There is a package `watermark` (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/watermark), maybe this is what you are looking for?

Comment: with a current latex you can use the shipout/background hook, e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/604943/2388

Answer (score 0):

An image to the background can be add by setting your own background template:

```tex
\usepackage{background}

\makeatletter
\def\bg@material{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node [rotate=0,scale=1,opacity=0.2,color=blue!30,xshift=-5mm,yshift=10mm]
at (current page.north east)  [anchor=north east]{\includegraphics[height=.2\paperheight]{etf-logo}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\makeatother
```

Here is an example below:

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\textwidth 155mm
\voffset -15mm
\oddsidemargin 5mm
\evensidemargin 5mm
\parindent 0pt
\parskip = .7\baselineskip

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage{background}

\makeatletter
\def\bg@material{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node [rotate=0,scale=1,opacity=0.2,color=blue!30,xshift=-5mm,yshift=10mm]
at (current page.north east)  [anchor=north east]{\includegraphics[height=.2\paperheight]{etf-logo}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Kodovi}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]