# Problems with watermark using background package

Tags: tikz-pgf, backgrounds

I want to place my image as a watermark at every page. Here's what I do in preamble:

```
\backgroundsetup{
    scale=1.5,
    angle=0,
    firstpage = true, 
    opacity=0.1, 
    contents = {
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node at ([yshift = 0pt, xshift = 0pt] current page.center){
                \includegraphics{shkolkovoLogo}
            }
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
}
```

which gives me this:

[image: pic1]

But I have two problems:

1. As soon as I have done it I saw this in my log

[image: pic2]

Strange thing, because everything was okay until I placed this watermark.

2. The watermark's opacity on the first page is somehow greater than on the others. Here's a photo of the first page

[image: pic3]

as you can see it's a bit different than what is shown on the very first picture.
What could be the reason of these things happen? Thank you in advance!

**MWE**, but it has a lot of errors on the last line

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\backgroundsetup{
    scale=1.5,
    angle=0,
    firstpage = true, 
    opacity=0.1, 
    contents = {
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node at ([yshift = 0pt, xshift = 0pt] current page.center){
                \includegraphics{example-image-duck};
            }
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
}  

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-150]
\end{document}
```

Comment: well read the error message: you forgot a semicolon at the end of the node. (I wouldn't use the background package and a tikzpicture to insert a simple graphic, you can do that directly with the shipout/background hook, see e.g https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/604943/2388).

Comment: I tried to place semicolon, but it doesn't change anything. I saw the link you added, but unfortunately I don't really understand how to do it. Would you be so kind to explain what does this shipout/background do and how to use it?

Comment: sorry but you didn't provide a small but complete example.

Comment: Example of code?

Comment: Did you add the semicolon after `\node at ([yshift = 0pt, xshift = 0pt] current page.center){ \includegraphics{shkolkovoLogo} } ;`? It is also possible that some errors stem from other parts of your document. You should always provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` so that others can compile it.

Comment: oh sorry I didn't know about MWE - I'm going to edit my question and add MWE. Thanks for that.
About that semicolon - yes I placed it right after I asked the question as I thought it would fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\backgroundsetup{
scale=1.5,
angle=0,
firstpage=true,
opacity=0.1,
contents={
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at ([xshift=0pt, yshift=0pt] current page.center){\includegraphics{example-image-duck}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

[image: Page with text and background image]

**Edit:** For me it seem that there is a bug in the `background` package. In the documentation it says:

> **firstpage=** This boolean option allows the user to specify, setting the value true, that the background material must be displayed only
> in the first page of the document. The deafulat value is false.

What really happens is that the material is placed on all pages independent of this option. -and It seems that the material is placed twice on the first page, if the option is true. -making the first page less opaque.

In your case, you can just keep the option with the default `false` like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\backgroundsetup{
scale=1.5,
angle=0,
contents={\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-150]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I feel so stupid that I just put the semicolon the wrong place...
But do you have any idea why opacity on the first page is different compare to other pages?

Comment: Thank you very much, that really helped me a lot!