# How to put an image next to text without it moving text. like in layer?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to put a QR code (PNG image) next to an address or centered title, at the beginning of a one-page document.
I need to document to remain one-page and readable; changing text size and margins is not acceptable.
There are ways to place the image withour affecting the text, but either nothing seems to work or is way above my head in comprehending. The example I have shows two routes I have tried that did not work.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=1cm,left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}


\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{main}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm]{triffids.png}
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}

%\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
%    \node[anchor=north east] (One) 
%    {\includegraphics[width=1pt]{nothing.png}};
%\end{tikzpicture}
%
%
%\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
%    \node[below=1cm of One] (Two)
%    {\includegraphics[width=3cm]{triffids.png}};
%\end{tikzpicture}


\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\pagewidth}{X c X}

{\Large\bfseries{To: Corny Klown University}} &  & From: Joe Spigot\\
Attention: Human Resources  & & Ornery, Ugly, Enchanting\\
Hiring Manager& & JoeSpigot@makeyuppy.com\\

\end{tabularx}

\indent To whom it will concern,\\

I am writing to throw my hat, as the saying goes, into the talent pool of professionals clowning around.\\
Blah\\
blah\\
lah\\
ah\\
...
Blah\\
blah\\
lah\\
ah\\
...Blah\\
blah\\
lah\\
ah\\
...Blah\\
blah\\
lah\\
ah\\
...Blah\\
blah\\
lah\\
ah\\
...Blah\\
blah\\
lah\\
ah\\
...Blah\\
blah\\
lah\\
ah\\
...Blah\\
blah\\
lah\\
ah\\
...Blah\\
blah\\
lah\\
ah\\
...Blah\\
blah\\
lah\\
ah\\
...Blah\\
blah\\
lah\\
ah\\
...Blah\\
blah\\
lah\\
ah\\
...Blah\\
blah\\
lah\\
ah\\
...Blah\\
blah\\
lah\\
\begin{center}\emph{Fin.}\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: a tikzpicture, even if it has size zero, is a box and so can affect spacing. Put it somewhere, where it doesn't affect the text, e.g. after a word or some other box like your tabularx. Or use the shipout/background hook: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/604943/2388

Comment: Note that the background layer in TikZ only controls the order in which layers are drawn inside the tikzpicture.  There is really no such thing as a background layer.

Comment: This is going to take some time to fiddle with.

I tried Ulrike's answer, and it does move text, but it is a start, only the image is drawn on the text, not text over the image. 

John's answer was helpful in clarifying the drawing order, and I will be investigating the link further. 

I find both answers are helpful in insight and leads. I will comment again when I see how these solutions work.

Comment: Have a look at one of the QR packages on ctan, like https://ctan.org/pkg/qrcode . Have a look at the wrapping approaches like wrapfig https://ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig or picins https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=picins .