How to force brutally an image to be put in a specific place, in a specific page
I am currently writing a thesis using a mandatory document class from my university that I obviously do not have access to.
It behaves like a black box that just print the title page using \frontmatter, then \maketitle if I declare it to be the document class. The problem is that on this title page, I need to put an image on the top-right corner, and nowhere else.
The only solution I see for the moment is to brutally force the image to be on page 1, and specifying manually the "coordinates" of the image, and sort of stick that image there no matter what is behind - which is completely okay for me... However, I have absolutely no idea on how I could "break" this system and force this image to be there, no matter the cost.
Does someone have an idea? Thanks
EDIT: Thanks to Ulrike's solution, just doing that before \frontmatter worked for me:
\AddToHookNext{shipout/background}
{\put(410,-155)
  {\includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{logo.png}}} 

I tried with several values before finding out the correct coordinates for my case.
Thank you for your help!

use a shipout hook, e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/604943/2388

Welcome! Is this being compiled on a university system, an online service or somewhere else? I assume you're not compiling it locally or you'd have to have access to the class file. How do you specify the details for the title page?

Do you get the PDF of the compiled document? If so, you have access to the class file. It has to be placed in a spot where LaTeX can read it, and as such you could embed the file into the PDF and then have it. Anyways, what @UlrikeFischer said.

@Skillmon I don't know that necessarily follows. (Though I agree it is very likely that the 'black box' isn't actually a black box.)

@cfr well, using a format it is actually possible to load the class without LaTeX having reading access to the .cls file. But I doubt they do that.

@Skillmon Oh, that's true, too. I was thinking of a case where your TeX install is on your server, you process the file and just push the generated files back to the user, but the user doesn't have the ability to inspect the files in the installation. That's not likely either.

See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/506766/pin-figure-to-page-and-column-in-a-2-column-document

@cfr but in that case you'd have reading access of the .clsin LaTeX and can embed it in the PDF. In your TeX code you could do something like\verbatiminput{mycls.cls}` to get a printed version of the code, but there are also possibilities to embed whole files (I think there is a package by Heiko, iirc).

@UlrikeFischer It worked, thank you so much!

@cfr Yes, I use Overleaf website, that's why I do not have access to the class file. The info in the title page is added with commands such as: \AcademicYear{2023/2024}, \advisor{...}, \title{....}, and then the \frontmatter and \maketitle does the rest for me. But anyway, it worked so I am happy with it!

Your picture solution may work fine on a trial-and-error basis (and keep doing what works!), but if you want to put an image precisely at a certain point on the current page, TikZ (tikz package) can do it: \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\path (current page.north east) ++ (-1in,-1in) node[anchor=north east] {\includegraphics[width=2in]{example-image-4x3}};} (I've included an image from the mwe package here)

@karlh There is no advantage to tikz here. It only adds overhead and requires a second compilation. (0,0) is the top left of the paper in the picture. There's no trial or error about it. See ltshipout-doc.pdf.

@cfr Good point (and I had forgotten you can do things like \put(1in,1in) rather than relying on unitlength). It is slightly harder to get, say, the top right corner of the image 1in left and below the upper right corner, as the point used for the \put is the lower left corner of the image. Unless there's an option to \includegraphics (or to \put) that I'm unaware of, and there might be....

@karlh You need a box in that case. But a box in a picture is a lot less overhead than a tikzpicture in a picture, which is what you'll probably end up with otherwise? (In this case, I mean. In other cases you can sometimes avoid the shipout hooks.)
