Half-page graphics
I'm trying to replicate a layout I've seen in some tabletop game books, where a piece of art takes up the entire top (or bottom, or left, or right) half of a page, going all the way to the gutter with no margins at all. For example, here's the latest version of Vampire the Masquerade.

The gray border is from my PDF reader, just to show that the image goes all the way to the edge of the page. Note that the header ("corebook" in the top left) does go on top of the image.
I know how to make an image go behind the text, using the background package. And I know how to put an image inline in the text, using graphicx. But I haven't found a way to make an image take up a certain portion of the page, going into the margins, but not overlapping the text. I've seen ways to make an inline image go all the way to the left and right edges of the paper, which gets me halfway there, but this still respects the top and bottom margins.
Is there a standard way to do this? I know I can use background to place the image at the top or bottom of the page, behind everything, but I haven't found a good way to scale it to the page width, or automatically figure out how far down to shift the text on that page. Alternately, using inline graphics would make the text get out of the way automatically, but I haven't found a good way to make it extend into the top or bottom margin.
(No MWE because I'm not sure what overall approach to take here.)

Have a look at the hvfloat package

Related/duplicate: How to include a picture over two pages, left part on left side, right on right (for books)?

you can use the shipout/background hook to place an image everywhere and in every size. If needed you can also add a white background on top for the text. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/604943/2388
